# firebase Cloud task permissioned denied although giving all permissions to service accounts

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I'm creating cloud tasks whenever new documentation got added to my firestore but cloud task invocation is failing with error permission denied "message: 'PERMISSION_DENIED(7): HTTP status code 403'"

Here is what I have done:
1- submitting new task (works)
[image]

2- task is failing with following error:
[image]

3- I have given all principles mentioned in the internet to selected below:
[image]

still failing!! any idea what I have missed ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling days I found the issue.

Basically, the URL of the cloud task creation was not correct. I created the cloud function URL based on my firebase location (say europe-central2), however, the cloud function URL trigger should be taken from the cloud platform itself :) as following (as you can see it us-central link):

[image]